# Запись данных в .txt построчно

Tags: c#, запись, txt

Как можно сделать запись данных из label на определенную строку(седьмую) в текстовом файле?

Comment: 1) считать все строки файла в память 2) поменять что вам надо 3) записать все обратно в файл

Comment: А как это можно сделать в форме кода?

Comment: По чтению и записи файлов на СО можно поиском тучу ответов найти, вы не пробовали?

Comment: Побывал, находил, но не совсем то что нужно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно вы хотите сделать что-то подобное.

```
int linesCount = 7; //колличество линий в файле
string[] _txtLine = new string[linesCount]
_txtLine[6]=label1.Text;
File.AppendAllLines(@"путь/к/вашему/файлу.txt",_txtLine);//вставить в существующий файл
File.WriteAllLines(@"путь/к/вашему/файлу.txt",_txtLine);//создать новый файл с вашими данными
```

Eсли вам нужно открывать какой-то файл откуда брать данные

```
_txtLine = File.ReadAllLines(@"путь/к/вашему/файлу.txt");
```

Советую почитать о классе [File](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=net-7.0)

Comment: а что будет если в файле 2 строки? А что будет если в файле 10 строк? Утрата данных оригинальной 7й строки?

Comment: @Andrew_STOP_RU_AGRESSION_IN_UA
 именно по этой причине контролируем размер линий через linesCount